# angular and error of attempting to configure _source for RouterOutlet and NgIf

Tags: angular, ngrx-router-store

I have an app where app.component only has router-outlet. I was having no issues until I added an `ng-template` for a ViewChild in a component 4 levels down from app component. Here is the structure:

AppComponent lazy loads FolderModule with FolderComponent. The folder component template is an ngFor that renders child components. It is the child component that has the ViewChild. I am not sure of a good way to explain this. I think the ngIf in the error is my ng-if that loads the page once there is data. I am hoping somebody recognises this error and can tell me what it means and why something so deep would cause an issue at the root of the app.  The ngIf part just keeps going:

Here is the line that causes it. The error is below:

```js
@ViewChild('performercontainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) performerContainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

> Attempting to configure '__source' with descriptor '{"value":"RouterOutlet","configurable":true}' on object 'function ViewContainerRef() {
>       }' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property __source, object is not extensible
>   zone.js:2257 Attempting to configure '__source' with descriptor '{"value":"NgIf","configurable":true}' on object 'function ViewContainerRef() {
>       }' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property __source, object is not extensible

Answer (score 4):

for anybody that comes across this.  The issue was that I am using storeFreeze from ngrx.  I removed that and the errors went away.  so I guess it was being a little aggressive.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Why is storeFreeze causing this issue? Thanks

Comment: My guess is that it is just too eager to check everything.  From what I could tell it had nothing to do with anything in my actual state.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @tubbsy's answer, you can opt in to use `MinimalRouterStateSerializer`, here's the quote from *@ngrx/router-store* [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration):

> RouterState.Minimal will use the MinimalRouterStateSerializer
>   serializer to serialize the Angular Router's RouterState and
>   RouterEvent.
>
> The difference between MinimalRouterStateSerializer and the default
>   RouterStateSerializer is that this serializer is fully serializable.
>   To make the state and the actions serializable, the properties
>   paramMap, queryParamMap and component are ignored.

```
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
  routerState: RouterState.Minimal,
});
```

The error happens because default `RouterStateSerializer` includes component class as property on store actions, so if you enable strict run-time immutability checks, the component class will get recursively frozen, which interferes with Angular DI ([this line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7d6f4885b25f36ab5262d868b0a4d762dea27a62/packages/core/src/view/util.ts#L222)). This [might cause issues with Ivy too](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2022#issuecomment-514374960).

Comment: I tried this and it asked me to update it to this run comment ng update @ngrx/store@8. It worked properly when I suggested a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who don't trust yourselves, or, more likely, your incompetent colleagues, to code immutably without Store Freeze: you can solve this conundrum by implementing the Custom State 'Serializer' as shown in the Ngrx docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the below code block in app.module.ts the problem will be solved.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
         StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
stateKey: 'router',
routerState: RouterState.Minimal
}),
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

`"@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0"` check the version. [check link](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8)
Must be 8 or higher.

To update your packages to the latest released version, run the command below.

> ng update @ngrx/store@8

V8 has the minimum version requirements:

- Angular version 8.x
- Angular CLI version 8.0.2
- TypeScript version 3.4.x
- RxJS version 6.4.0

RouterState.Minimal will use the MinimalRouterStateSerializer serializer to serialize the Angular Router's RouterState and RouterEvent.

The difference between MinimalRouterStateSerializer and the default RouterStateSerializer is that this serializer is fully serializable. To make the state and the actions serializable, the properties paramMap, queryParamMap and component are ignored.

```
 StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
                stateKey: 'router',
                routerState: RouterState.Minimal
    }),
```