# Why do I get "TypeError: property of '__source' is undefined : object is not extensible." error in IE11?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I get that error in IE 11. 
The full error:

> Attempting to configure '__source' with descriptor '{"value":"DefaultValueAccessor","configurable":true}' on object 'function ElementRef(nativeElement) {
>               this.nativeElement = nativeElement;
>           }' and got error, giving up: TypeError: property of '__source' is undefined : object is not extensible.

My code:

```
for(let x = 0; x < this.files.length; x++) {

      let filename = this.files[x].name.slice((Math.max(0, this.files[x].name.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);

      for(let y = 0; y < acceptedFileExtensions.length; y ++) {
        if(filename === acceptedFileExtensions[y]) {
          this.supportedSelectedFiles.push(this.files[x]);
          formData.append('files', this.files[x]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Then I upload the form data with an HTTP post to my server. What is the solution to make this work in IE 11 too?

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework (e.g., Angular, React)? This looks like something from that rather than your code.

Comment: Yes its Angular. @HereticMonkey

Comment: Might take a look at other questions with this error in an Angular context, like [angular and error of attempting to configure _source for RouterOutlet and NgIf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51410091). Different location, but could be similar solution.

Comment: I checked it out, his problem was caused by storeFreeze from ngrx which I don't use in my app. @HereticMonkey

Comment: Yeah, don't know what's going on. I found [this github issue, which shows a large number of reasons...](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1104).